# External Libraries in File Reading

Tags: java, file, libraries

Right now I am working on a project where I have to read a series of Strings in from a text file in java.

I know how to do it in the general way (using a FileReader, Buffer, etc.). My issue arises because I am not allowed to use external libraries at all. Are these considered external libraries?

To put things more easily, whats a good definition of an external library? Is it anything that I would have to import?

As a follow up question, how would I be able to read from a text file without using any of those libraries, if they're not allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External libraries would be ones you download that do not come with Java API. An example would be the apache commons API. If you can just import it then it's not an external library.